# ファイル名を111.jpegのように数字で管理していて、xargs -n2 mv で一括で番号を振り直しをしたいのですが、どうしても一部のファイルが消えてしまいます。

Tags: macos, command-line, zsh, shell

```
ls
1.jpeg
2.jpeg
3.jpeg
11.jpeg
12.jpeg
13.jpeg
101.jpeg
102.jpeg
103.jpeg
```

数字の部分を２増やしたい

```
ls | sed s/\.jpeg// | awk '{print $1".jpeg"" " $1+2".jpeg"}'
1.jpeg 3.jpeg
101.jpeg 103.jpeg
102.jpeg 104.jpeg
103.jpeg 105.jpeg
11.jpeg 13.jpeg
12.jpeg 14.jpeg
13.jpeg 15.jpeg 
2.jpeg 4.jpeg
3.jpeg 5.jpeg
```

これをxargs -n2 mvに入れると

```
 ls | sed s/\.jpeg// | awk '{print $1".jpeg"" " $1+2".jpeg"}'| xargs -n2 mv
ls
104.jpeg    105.jpeg    14.jpeg     15.jpeg     4.jpeg      5.jpeg
```

101.jpeg,11.jpeg,1.jpegが消えてしまいます。

マイナスで試すとうまくいきます。

```
ls | sed s/\.jpeg// | awk '{print $1".jpeg"" " $1-2".jpeg"}'| xargs -n2 mv
ls
-1.jpeg     0.jpeg      1.jpeg      10.jpeg     100.jpeg    101.jpeg    11.jpeg     9.jpeg      99.jpeg
```

printfでやってみると

```
ls| sed -e s/.jpeg//| awk '{printf ("%d%s %d%s\n",$1,".jpeg",$1+2,".jpeg")}'
1.jpeg 3.jpeg
101.jpeg 103.jpeg
102.jpeg 104.jpeg
103.jpeg 105.jpeg
11.jpeg 13.jpeg
12.jpeg 14.jpeg
13.jpeg 15.jpeg
2.jpeg 4.jpeg
3.jpeg 5.jpeg

ls| sed -e s/.jpeg//| awk '{printf ("%d%s %d%s\n",$1,".jpeg",$1+2,".jpeg")}'| xargs -n2 mv
ls
104.jpeg    105.jpeg    14.jpeg     15.jpeg     4.jpeg      5.jpeg
```

やはり101.jpeg,11.jpeg,1.jpegが消えてしまいます。
1.jpegから136.jpegで試すと

```
ls
10.jpeg     100.jpeg    101.jpeg    11.jpeg     137.jpeg    138.jpeg
```

8,9,98,99,135,136以外のファイルが消えてしまいます。
法則性がなんなのかわかりません。
基礎的な知識がないのでネットで参照させてもらっても解決できずにいます。
面倒な質問で申し訳ないですがご助力いただければ幸いです。

Comment: 「101.jpeg,11.jpeg,1.jpegが消えてしまいます。」とのことですが、例えば `1.jpeg` には `mv 1.jpeg 3.jpeg` が実行されます。これは意図通りですよね？ そうすると「消える」のは当然と思いますが、質問者さんの予想としては、どうなるはずでしたか？ (なお、その後 `mv 3.jpeg 5.jpeg` も実行されますので、`1.jpeg` は最終的には `5.jpeg` になるはずです。これは質問者さんの意図とは違うかも知れませんね。）

Comment: なるほど自分で上書きがループさせていたんですね。自分の意図は、1ページ->3ページ,3ページ->5 ページ,5ページ->7ページなどと、テキスト自炊をしていてスキャン一枚撮り忘れたので、ナンバリングがずれていたのを治すためでした。素早い返信ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 意図どおりにならない原因

```
ls | sed s/\.jpeg// | awk '{print $1".jpeg"" " $1+2".jpeg"}'| xargs -n2 mv
```

の場合

mvを実行せず、echoでどんなコマンドを実行しているのか調べてみると、

```
ls | sed s/\.jpeg// | awk '{print $1".jpeg"" " $1+2".jpeg"}'| xargs -n2 echo mv
```

結果は以下のようになりました。

```
mv 1.jpeg 3.jpeg
mv 101.jpeg 103.jpeg
mv 102.jpeg 104.jpeg
mv 103.jpeg 105.jpeg
mv 11.jpeg 13.jpeg
mv 12.jpeg 14.jpeg
mv 13.jpeg 15.jpeg
mv 2.jpeg 4.jpeg
mv 3.jpeg 5.jpeg
```

せっかく101.jpegを103.jpegに変えた後に103.jpegを105.jpegに変えています。

#### 対処

`ls`の代わりに`ls -r`とすればうまくいきそうです。

```
ls -r | sed s/\.jpeg// | awk '{print $1".jpeg"" " $1+2".jpeg"}'| xargs -n 2 echo mv
```

結果

```
mv 3.jpeg 5.jpeg
mv 2.jpeg 4.jpeg
mv 13.jpeg 15.jpeg
mv 12.jpeg 14.jpeg
mv 11.jpeg 13.jpeg
mv 103.jpeg 105.jpeg
mv 102.jpeg 104.jpeg
mv 101.jpeg 103.jpeg
mv 1.jpeg 3.jpeg
```

---

【追記】
lsのソートは辞書順なので、問題があります。
例えば

```
1.jpeg  101.jpeg  102.jpeg  103.jpeg  11.jpeg  12.jpeg  13.jpeg  2.jpeg  3.jpeg  9.jpeg
```

の場合、9.jpegを11.jpegに変更したあと、11.jpegを13.jpegに変更してしまいます。

数値順にソートすればこの問題は回避できそうです。

```
ls -1 | sort -rg | sed s/\.jpeg// | awk '{print $1".jpeg"" " $1+2".jpeg"}'| xargs -n 2 echo mv
```

`ls -r`を`ls -1 | sort -rg`に変えて数値順にソートしています。

Comment: echo で調べることができるんですね。勉強になります。ご回答通りls -r で降順で並び替えてechoを外すと、意図通りになりました。素早い解決策をご教示ありがとうございました。

Comment: @jmt 問題がありました。回答の追記をご確認ください。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。数値を足す場合は一行ずつ降順で数値に直してソートすればいいんですね。勉強になります。

Answer (score 2):

既に原因は判明していますので、参考までに arithmetic expansion を使う方法を挙げておきます。POSIX complient なので bash 以外でも有効な機能かと思います(実際、dash でも実行可能です)。

```bash
$ command ls -1r | while IFS=. read -r a ext;do mv "$a.$ext" "$((a+2)).$ext";done
```

**追記**

GNU coreutils に含まれている `ls` コマンドには「数値」順でファイル名をソートするオプションスイッチ(`-v`)があります。

```bash
$ ls --version
ls (GNU coreutils) 8.32

$ man ls

-v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

Comment: 有益な回答ありがとうございます。不勉強な自分にはもう少し理解する時間がかかりそうですが、ご参考にさせていただきます。他の人がまさに探している答えかもしれないので

Comment: 有意義だと思われます。お時間いただいてありがとうございます。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。前のコメントは一行ずつ降順でlsして環境変数を設定してピリオドで区切って変数に代入してループするのですね。短くてオシャレな書き方ですね。 lsをmanコマンドすることはなかったので勉強になります。